# PySide2/Python 2.7 : Having a QGraphicsItem receiving a keyPressEvent

Tags: python, qgraphicsitem, pyside2

I am having trouble with passing a keyPressEvent in my custom QGraphicsItem, and I am not sure if I understand well how it works on this kind of objects. I know it has been asked already and I have found a lot of similar questions in C++ and a few in Python, but I could not make it work in my script...

In Qt's documentation it is said:

```
Note that key events are only received for items that set the ItemIsFocusable flag, 
and that have keyboard input focus.
```

My guess is that something is wrong in my code related to this sentence.

Basically, my class looks like that:

```
class myItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(myItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event == QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete:
            self.scene().removeItem(self)
        return super(myItem, self).keyPressEvent(event)
```

Am I missing a flag, or do I need to set up something in my scene class, or something like that?

Cheers :)

Comment: I believe you have to use a QGraphicsObject instead of a QGraphicsItem. EDIT: maybe not, i might have confused something

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure I'll provide it asap! I didn't think it would need to be tested since it is not an error per say.